# URL variable not being set in PHP when using jquery mobile

Tags: php, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

i have a few pages and when the input is submitted it will go to a php file which checks the url variable this could be executeeffects.php?option=blockuser

but when i go to the page the page just says "undefined" in the executeeffects php file it has a checking feature to check if a variable is set, it echos out one thing if it is or another thing if it isnt, however i didnt make it echo undefined so i dont no where that is coming from, the code is below

can someone tell me if this is a problem with jquery mobile or if im missing something please?

block.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
    <title>Ryan Kelly</title> 

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1 user-scalable=no"> 

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="effects.js"></script>
    </head> 
    <body> 

    <div data-role="page">

<div data-role="header">
    <h1>Ryan Kelly</h1>
</div><!-- /header -->

<div data-role="content">   
    <label for="basic">Username:</label>
     <input type="text" name="name" id="basic" value="" />
     <input type="text" name="name" id="blocked" value="" />
     <a href="executeeffects.php?option=block" data-role="button" class="button">Submit</a>

     <?php include('listusers.php'); ?>
 </div><!-- /content -->

     </div><!-- /page -->

     </body>
   </html>
```

executeeffects.php

```
<?php


if(isset($_GET['option'])){

echo 'something is set!';
} else {

echo 'nothing is set!';
}

?>
```

Comment: What does var_dump($_GET); output on executeeffects.php

Comment: its suppose to check if something is set but instead of echo either one statement or the other it just goes to the executeeffects page with it saying undefined

Comment: Remove the code inside executeeffects.php and replace it with var_dump($_GET); does it output anything?

Comment: it says undefined , but when i refresh the page it says array(1) { ["option"]=> string(5) "block" }

Comment: Is that code supplied in your question the only code inside executeeffects.php?

Comment: yes and i removed it all and added what you told me to put but i have backup on my desktop

Answer (score 0):

You Said "**i have a few pages and when the input is submitted it will go to a php file which checks the url variable this could be executeeffects.php?option=blockuser**"

This:

```
<input type="text" name="name" id="basic" value="" />
 <input type="text" name="name" id="blocked" value="" />
 <a href="executeeffects.php?option=block" data-role="button" class="button">Submit</a>
```

will not submit the value of the inputs unless you are using some type of **jQuery** that you have not posted in which case this will need to be done differently.

to submit the value of the inputs you need to use a `<form>`